# Iteration while entering elements in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to make a simple linked list in C. But program just skips the input of  " **Enter more nodes?[y/n]**" part.
Here's my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*start = NULL;

void createlist()
{
    int item;
    char choice = 'y';

    struct node *newNode;
    struct node *current;

    while(choice != 'n')
    {
        printf("Enter item to add in the Linked List\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &item);

        newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        newNode->data = item;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        if(start == NULL)
        {
            start = newNode;
            current = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            current->next = newNode;
            current = newNode;
        }

        printf("Enter more nodes?[y/n]\n");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct node *new_node;
    printf("Your node is :\n");
    new_node = start;
    while(new_node!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ---> ", new_node->data );
        new_node = new_node->next;

    }
}

int main()
{
    createlist();
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
[Program skipping choice input part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av7qG.png)

But when I change **choice** varaiable to **int** from **char**, program runs perfectly.
Here's the working function:

```
void createlist()
{
    int item;
    int choice = 1;

    struct node *newNode;
    struct node *current;

    while(choice != 0)
    {
        printf("Enter item to add in the Linked List\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &item);

        newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        newNode->data = item;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        if(start == NULL)
        {
            start = newNode;
            current = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            current->next = newNode;
            current = newNode;
        }

        printf("Enter more nodes?\n[NO - 0, YES - 1]\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
}
```

Can you guys please tell me why program works incorrectly when **choice** is **char** type?

Comment: My experience: `newline` and `space` are troublemakers when mixed with `scanf`, as they are actually `char`, while `integer` are altogether different data type. That is the reason you observed such behavior. Don't worry about it much. Play safe and use %d...:)

Comment: Thanks bro! Working correctly now. :-)

Comment: use  `scanf("%s", &choice);` it will work . . .

Comment: You can also add a `getch()` after scanf to consume `'\n'` char in buffer

Comment: Ohhk..Thanks for help! :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `newline` left in the input buffer which is being read for the `%c` format. Change

```
scanf("%c", &choice);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);`
```

The leading space tells `scanf` to clean off whitespace first. This happens automatically with the `%d` format.